# Disable unity sidebar but still use dash with superkey

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Is there a way to disable the unity sidebar but still use the dash?

Comment: What do you mean by 'disable'?

Comment: Dashboard is a unity feature. How can you disable Unity but continue using one of its feature? However you can use Gnome if you want.

Comment: i dislike the sidebar but i like the bar at the top, and gnome doesnt has this bar. but i unterstood, its impossible to disable (i mean remove) the sidebar. i only want to disable one feature of unity and still using the other features, not unity in general. regrets malte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of. Go into system settings > appearance > behavior and set the launcher to auto-hide. Then set the reveal sensitivity to its lowest possible setting and it will hide permanently. I've just tested this and it works.

Comment: thx it works, but cause of animations like minimazing, update center or starting a program you will still recognize the sidebar.

Comment: Unfortunately, with dual-monitors, Unity still renders a "sticky" monitor border to catch the sidebar activitation, even if it's set to nothing. This makes using Unity with dual monitors really annoying because your mouse will get "stuck" on the monitor edges.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can do these steps for disabling some Unity animation:

1. Open CompizConfig Settings Manager.
2. Go to the Ubuntu Unity Plugin.
3. Go to experimental tab and deactivate "Enable Shortcut Hint Overlay" check box and from Launch Animation and Urgent Animation combo box select None.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an "experimental" tab in 14.04.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the Dash shortcut via compiz. Tested on Ubuntu 14.04

1. Open CompizConfig Settings Manager.
2. Go to the Ubuntu Unity Plugin.
3. Go to 'Launcher Tab' and click `<Super>` Button
4. Uncheck the Enable checkbox

[image]

Comment: This is the exact opposite of why the OP asked for. This disables superkey but keeps the horrible sidebar.