# How can I only disable unity panel?

Tags: 12.04, unity, cairo-dock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable unity sidebar but still use dash with superkey](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154560/disable-unity-sidebar-but-still-use-dash-with-superkey)

I use Ubuntu 12.04, I am going to use Cairo-dock as my panel and task bar. I only want to disable unity panel and continue using dash search feature. I do not want unity panel track my open task.

How can I do it?

Comment: I did it but unity panel consume memory and track my open application yet. I want to disable it completely, I do not want to hide it.

Comment: I think it is not possible to use the dash feature alone without having unity. Anyways wait for some core unity geeks to answers this.